# iOS import header files in different system version in iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter

It is always true , and I don`t  know how to work it, it is emergency, please have a look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoGt0.png

Answer (score 0):

## if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0)

## import

@interface AppController ()

## else

@interface AppController ()

## endif